# Начальное значение SERIAL в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

как мне задать начальное значение для SERIAL в постгрес? Собираюсь использовать сериал для столбца id и я подумал,что лучше будет начать нумерацию айдишников ,скажем, с миллиона

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SERIAL` (и `BIGSERIAL`) это типы, которые автоматически создают `SEQUENCE` для генерации значения. При определении поля нет возможности влиять на то, как создается эта последовательность.

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname SERIAL
);
```

эквивалентно

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
);
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
```

Нужно либо вручную ее создавать и поле определять так, что она использовалась. Т.е. сделать второй вариант заменив создание на:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq START WITH 1000000;
```

Либо более простой способ - изменить ее паратметры после создания таблицы:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq RESTART WITH 1000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь стандартным синтаксисом (стандартным в том смысле, что определённом в SQL стандарте) [`GENERATED AS IDENTITY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). Для этого синтаксиса, в отличии от синтаксического сахара-псевдотипа `serial`, реализована возможность задать параметры нижележащего `sequence`

```
create table tablename (
  id int generated always as identity (start 1000) primary key,
  -- прочие данные
);
```